# Breakpoint in Manager class not being hit in Junit test - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, junit, android-testing

So I am running a few tests in AndroidJunit, which tests a manager class that I created for my application.  When I add breakpoints to the Test class and go into debug mode, they get hit just fine.  But if I add break points to the Manager class that I am testing in junit, they do not get hit when I run the tests.  Is it possible to hit break points in a non-test class when running junit in Android Studio? I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to solve this issue.  Logs also do not show up when I place them outside of the Test class.

**EDIT/UPDATE**

So I have been able to dig a little deeper and found out that the problem here was using Mockito with my Tests.  So if I replace `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()` with `context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);` then the debugger no longer hits the breakpoints placed in the manager.  However, I need to use Mockito with my tests, so I'm in a bit of a predicament.  Does anyone if there is a manner that I can use Mockito in that allows me to set and reach break points in a non-test class? Thank you.

FYI, I am passing context into the manager class method like this
`manager.checkSharedPreferences(context)`, and the manager is extracting values from shared preferences.